# Swift Firebase - User Registration with Profile Photo

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to register user information and add profile photo.
The problem is Firebase documentation only provide way to create user with email and password, it works, but how do i follow to register more information ?

```
func createNewUser(name: String, email: String, phone: String, photo: UIImage, password: String, onCompletion: @escaping (Bool, RequestErrors?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            onCompletion(false, .authError)
            return
        }
        onCompletion(true, nil)
    }
}
```

I'm passing the informations to this function by parameters but i don't know how to proceed.
Any help ?

Comment: Save other user information in firebase database. Upload photo to Firebase storage separately

Comment: ok, but in what order? first the data and then the photo or the photo first and then the data?

Comment: You should insert data first and asynchronously upload profile picture as well. After successful profile pic upload, you can add profile image url in user data

Comment: Thank you @NightFury. I'll do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store more information for the user, you need to use either Firebase Database or Firestore. You'd have to add one to your pod file.

For example, here's how setting the email for the user in the database would work

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()

self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["email": user's email])
```

For image storage you need to use Storage, and it would work similarly. You would also need to update your pod file. You would create a reference to store the images. So something like users/profilepics/uid.jpg Then you'd have an upload task to upload the image to the reference. Check out the Firebase Storage documentation on this for more.

Comment: hum nice, the logic sounds good but in what order i do? first the data and then the photo or the photo first and then the data?

Comment: I would say it doesn't really matter. You may want to do the photo first to give it time to upload and then you can retrieve the URL from Storage and then set that in the database as "profilePicUrl" along with your other key:values in the same `.setValue` array.

Comment: in my case i figured out that i need to upload the photo first then register all the data. i'll post the resolution code for future research.

Answer (score 0):

That is the final code.

```
func createNewUser(name: String, email: String, phone: String, photo: UIImage, password: String, onCompletion: @escaping (Bool, RequestErrors?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            onCompletion(false, .authError)
            return
        }

        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).jpg")

        guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }

        if let uploadData = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    guard let photoUrl = url else { return }
                    let values = ["displayName": name, "email": email, "phoneNumber": phone, "photoURL": photoUrl.absoluteString]
                    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
                    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err!)
                            return
                        }
                        User.shared = User(uid: uid, displayName: name, email: email, phoneNumber: phone, photoURL: photoUrl)
                        onCompletion(true, nil)
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

When i get all the data that i need i fill my User singleton.